# How to identify a user by sending a tagged link to the user's email inbox?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am new to google analytics and google tag manager , so any help and clarification would be appreciated.

I am trying to understand how to track users via tagged email links in GTM and GA....
Is it possible to include a user ID in an email link and then catch the client id in GTM when user clicks on the link?

What I am trying to do is to detect different devices that an Anonymous user can use while exploring my website. So I am thinking maybe it is possible to get the user ID linked to each email from my database , include it in a link which is used in an email template.
Then when a user clicks on the link , based on the clicked event , a tag on GTM side can catch it , extract User ID and get the Client id (from GTM) and use these values to identify the user . Is this doable ? If yes where should I start from? If no , is there any way to do this?

Regards,
Lina

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do it and the procedure described can work. Send that information as custom dimensions in Google Analytics tag in GTM (config them in Google Analytics UI at Property level). You can also create an User-ID view and send userId parameter as Field to set in GTM too (as well as a custom dimension).

Comment: Thanks Michele ... will try to implement this today... will update the question accordingly.